# Icons too big after migration from 14.04 to 16.04

Tags: 14.04, 16.04, gnome, upgrade

My machine was in 14.04 with gnome fallback
I ve started the update towards 16.04, went ok.
Now when I log in the icons are just enormous"[image]

If I log in with guest session, it goes on Unity with correct size.
[image]

Someone knows files to erase or modify to fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to open `unity-control-center`, then select Displays in it and set other screen *Resolution* (preferable native for your monitor):

- from terminal with

  ```
  unity-control-center display
  ```
- from GUI by clicking on *Gear* in top right, select *System settings* and then *Displays* (you can move window by clicking <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd>).
- or programmatically (change `'1920x1080+0+0'` below to your resolution, second part resets scaling which may be the problem too)

  ```
  sudo apt-get install dconf-cli

  dconf write /org/compiz/profiles/unity/plugins/core/outputs "['1920x1080+0+0']"

  dconf write /org/gnome/desktop/interface/scaling-factor 'uint32 0'
  dconf write /org/gnome/desktop/interface/cursor-size 24
  dconf write /org/gnome/desktop/interface/text-scaling-factor 1.0
  dconf write /org/compiz/profiles/unity/plugins/unityshell/icon-size 48
  ```

  if above does not help try XRandr - `xrandr -s 1920x1080`.

If you do not have personal settings of Unity and/or GNOME you may want to backup

```
dconf dump / > dconf_backup
```

and then reset them with:

```
dconf reset -f /org/compiz/
dconf reset -f /org/gnome/
dconf reset -f /com/ubuntu/user-interface/
```

also try

```
unity --reset
```

Comment: Thanks, will try but the window will be so big that I will not be able to navigate into it. But will keep you posted.

Comment: Updated answer with other variants.

Comment: The above commands do not change anything. The resolution is set to the 1920x1080 (max) for  the screen I  have.

Comment: Very strange, I can't understand what happens. How it is possible - big interface parts with correct high resolution... Only icons are big? Or windows are big too? You can try to install GNOME FlashBack (`sudo apt-get install gnome-panel`) and set resolution from it.

Comment: I ve unistall gnome-flashback, reinstalled it: Same issue.

Comment: Have you tried logging in to GNOME Flashback and set resolution from it?

Comment: Yes I did. The command line should have done the trick too in that case, ( refering about from above 1920x1080+0+0) but it did not.  So how come guest user is not affected while my user is affected by that scaling problem in ALL environment (compiz, metacity, ubuntu default?). Note that guest user does not have any problem in compiz, metacity and ubuntu default GUI.

Comment: Sorry for the delay but installing dconf and performing the reset worked as instructed.

Answer (score 1):

For Ubuntu 17 the following works

1. Open nautilus app
2. Right corner select view 'grid icon'
3. Use mouse scroll to adjust thumbnail size
4. Now go to desktop see the changes.